# How to hide the blue sphere behind the 'background', but over the edge of the 'container'

Tags: html, css

The design calls for the blue sphere to be behind the 'background', but over the edge of the container.
Design by Drippple artist Camila Cat: [https://dribbble.com/Camila_cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb8V6.png)
Code: First off my code is here:
https://codepen.io/misterhtmlcss/pen/VXxVvQ

I have no idea how to cover the exterior of the sphere that overlaps with the background, while allowing it (the sphere in the top left corner) to STILL cover the top left corner of the 'container'.

------ Structural HTML included here for simplicity -----
------ START HTML -----

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="top-border"> </div>
    <div class="card-body"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-left"></div>
</div>
```

------- End HTML ------

------- SCSS -------

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

$background: #eef1f8;
$card: rgb(253, 253, 253);
$shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(grey, 0.6);
$green: rgb(0, 216, 178);
$yellow: rgb(255, 213, 111);
$blue: rgb(0, 177, 250);

body {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $background;
    width: 850px;
    padding: 100px 125px;
}

.card {
    background-color: $card;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 650px;
    position: relative;

    .top-border {
        height: 10px;
        background-color: $green;
    }
    .card-body {
        height: 330px;
        .text {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: 60px;
            li {
                position: relative;
                top: 40px;
                left: -40px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.avatar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -70px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}

.qrcode {
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}

li {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: darkgrey;
    line-height: 1.5;
    list-style-type: none;
}

img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1,
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
}

.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: -250px;
    top: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: $blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 150px rgb(173, 220, 239);
    z-index: 5;
}
```

------- END SCSS -------

Comment: It is not what is the problem. Plz elaborate

Comment: remove the .top-left css class

Comment: Link to the design: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1428478/screenshots/4380842/800600.jpg

Comment: @Fecosos your links to codepen aren't working for me. Sorry Fecosos. Are you saving it? I looked at your recent Pens and didn't find it there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

I just hide outside portion of the top-left circle from container. `overflow: hidden;`

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/vishnuprasad/pen/RMBYKv

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $background;
    width: 850px;
    padding: 100px 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: -260px;
    top: -260px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #00b1fa;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 150px rgb(173, 220, 239);
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!! Thank you thank you!!! I'm going to take a really close look at how you did it different from me, because I tried so many variations besides what you saw and I was stumped. Have a great week!!

Comment: @misterhtmlcss Glad to help you! If it is helpful, please accept my answer by click on the "Check" button.